# Extracting bit flags in AWK and the 'and($1,0x1)' statement

Tags: awk

Could someone please explain the meaning of statement like `and($1,1)` in AWK, give some typical usage examples, and possibly explain the behavior in the code snippets below? I know a statement like this can be used to extract bit flags, but I was not able to find any reference in the AWK user guide on how to properly use it.

```
echo "1\n3" | gawk '{if (and($1, 0x2)) print}'
3

echo "1\n3" | gawk '{if (and($1, 0x1)) print}'
1
3

echo "1\n3" | gawk '{if (and($1, 1)) print}'
1
3

echo "1\n3" | gawk '{if (and($1, 2)) print}'
3

echo "1\n3" | gawk '{if (and($1, 3)) print}'
1
3
```

Comment: [GNU Awk User's Guide -  Bit-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html#Bitwise-Functions)

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies a lot. It's embarrassing how I missed this 'bit' of the guide.

Comment: No worries, I've been accused of being blind in one eye and not being able to see out of the other before -- welcome to programming....

Answer (score 0):

The function call `and($1, 1)` returns `1` (true) when `$1` is odd, and `O` (false) otherwise. For example

```sh
echo $'1\n2\n3\n4' | awk '{print and($1, 1)}'
```

gives as output:

```
1
0
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

*was not able to find any reference in the AWK user guide on how to properly use it.*

From [man awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)

```
Bit Manipulations Functions

Starting with version 3.1 of gawk, the following bit manipulation functions are available. They work by converting double-precision floating point values to uintmax_t integers, doing the operation, and then converting the result back to floating point. The functions are:
and(v1, v2)

Return the bitwise AND of the values provided by v1 and v2.

compl(val)

Return the bitwise complement of val.

lshift(val, count)

Return the value of val, shifted left by count bits.

or(v1, v2)

Return the bitwise OR of the values provided by v1 and v2.

rshift(val, count)

Return the value of val, shifted right by count bits.

xor(v1, v2)

Return the bitwise XOR of the values provided by v1 and v2.
```

Note that this require `gawk` version 3.1 or newer, thus code relying on it might fail in other versions.